# How to get PI in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pi

I could not find any information about mathemtical constants in the Tensorflow API

neither in [Basic Math functions](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/math_ops/basic_math_functions) nor in [Math Ops](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/math_ops).

I was able to get it by

```
import math as m
pi = tf.constant(m.pi)
```

However, this would mean to include another library, - so I wonder if there is this functionallity for mathemtical  constants like `pi`, or `euler` already provided inside tensorflow?

Comment: Hi, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45995471/how-to-get-pi-in-tensorflow/77193163#77193163:~:text=tensorflow.experimental.numpy) which I've provided answers your question, please accept and upvote

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`math` is [in the Python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html), not a third-party module.

I don't see why using it is a problem whatsoever.

Comment: sry , did not meant third party library - I editet my question. I could not find a anything related to mathematical constans in tensorflow and want to know if they are provided in tf

Comment: AFIK, even standard library is not included in tensorflow graph.

Answer (score 5):

As I know NO, and there's a reason for it. If each library define it own pi will be lots of code duplications!
You did it right

Answer (score 2):

Tensorflow already has `pi` and `e` in [tensorflow.experimental.numpy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/experimental/numpy)

```py
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> from tensorflow.experimental import numpy as tnp # start using tnp instead of numpy or math library
>>> tnp.pi, tnp.e
3.141592653589793, 2.718281828459045
```